# Send HTTP request from VC++ file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, http

I am trying to send an HTTP request with the contents of a file set as the body of the HTTP request and want to get the response from a server using VC++.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

I think I was not very clear with what I wanted to do or I misunderstood the answers. Neways, what I want to accomplish is, one of my web-services accepts the data of a local file as the body of the HTTP request sent to it. I want to make a call to this service and send the contents of a txt file as the body of the HTTP request. In return I will get a response from the service which I want to get in a string variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cURL library](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html). There is also a similar topic [Programmatically reading a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389069/programmatically-reading-a-web-page)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use WinInet.   Check out the docs here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385331(VS.85).aspx

HTH

Colby Africa