# C++ interface version of HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, httpwebrequest

We are wondering how to use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse .net framework Class in ATL c++ project is their any interface exposed for webrequest class in C++, currently we cannot have a c# project so we are looking for alternative interface.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Ramanand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following options:

1) Write your managed HttpWebRequest code into a C# file, and compile it as a DLL. Use RegAsm.exe to register it as a COM object. Use the COM object from the C/C++ application.

2) As Michael has suggested above, use Managed C++ to write the code, and interop/interface with other parts of your C/C++ code.

3) Dont use managed code! Use the platform specific libraries - for eg, [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382925(VS.85).aspx) from Microsoft is well tested, and supported for both client side and server side operations. You can also use [Wininet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385483(VS.85).aspx) which is what is used by Internet Explorer, however it is not recommended for use in Middle-tier scenarios.

So,unless you really need something that is offered by System.Net managed code namespace that is not available on Wininet/WinHTTP, I would not opt for managed code. Managed code will bring in memory and cpu overhead that is really not needed if all you are doing is downloading web pages.

Comment: Really thanks for the update i will b using WinHttp/Wininet method to download method.

Answer (score 2):

please refer to this post: [How do you make a HTTP request with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c)

[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) is recommended in many posts.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use C++/CLI.  A code snippet might look something like this.

```
// Open a connection
System::Net::HttpWebRequest ^_HttpWebRequest = safe_cast<System::Net::HttpWebRequest^>(System::Net::HttpWebRequest::Create(_URL));

_HttpWebRequest->AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

// You can specify additional header values:
_HttpWebRequest->UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
_HttpWebRequest->Referer = "http://www.google.com/";

// set timeout for 20 seconds (Optional)
_HttpWebRequest->Timeout = 20000;

// Request response:
System::Net::WebResponse ^_WebResponse = _HttpWebRequest->GetResponse();

// Open data stream:
System::IO::Stream ^_WebStream = _WebResponse->GetResponseStream();

// Do something with stream
_tmpImage = Image::FromStream(_WebStream);

// Cleanup
_WebResponse->Close();
_WebResponse->Close();
```