# Windows C++ Should I use WinHttp library or XmlHttp from MSXML?

Tags: c++, windows, xmlhttprequest, winhttp

A rather simple question. Should I use the `WinHttp` library to make a web service request in my C++ programs or should I use the `IXmlHttpRequest` interface in the `msxml` library to send web service requests? Obviously the `WinHttp` library provides a lot more fine control compared to the `IXmlHttpRequest` library. But the `XmlHttpRequest` object is a `w3.org` standard and in theory more portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends whether you are accessing the service on secure channel i.e. HTTPS or simple one i.e. HTTP.

As per MSDN (`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891732.aspx`), IXMLHttpRequest supports only HTTP.

> > > Note   IXMLHTTPRequest does not support secure website access. To access a secure website, use the WinINet API.

But WinInet API is quite old and have some multi-threading issues (I think its there on MSDN too)...

So the best bet is WinHTTP for HTTPS and HTTP, otherwise good old IXMLHttpRequest.

**Note:** libcurl and curlpp (c++ port of libcurl) is also there to check. There is an old post for this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c`

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to your "simple question": You should use what you feel most comfortable in and what best fits to your requirements.

You could also consider the [http client in boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp).