# How do i call a http handler from a c++ application.?

Tags: c#, c++, http, httphandler

How do i call a .net http handler from a c++ application?

Thanks,
subs

Answer (score 1):

Generally the most convenient way of doing this is going to be with a plain old-fashioned HTTP request to the associated url; so then the question becomes "how do I make an HTTP request from c++?"

Luckily: [How do you make a HTTP request with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c)