# Reading text from a website in C++

Tags: c++, dropbox

I am currently coding a chat application-like-thing, and it writes and reads from a .txt file on DropBox in my 'public' folder. I was wondering how exactly I could achieve this.

My code so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string output;
    string outputty;
    string Chat;
    string option;

    string line;
    ofstream players;
    ifstream chat;
    fstream chatw;

    cout << "(1) - Enter\n";
    cin >> option;
    if (option == "1") {
        players.open ("C:/Users/Pebsie/Dropbox/Public/data.txt");
        string name;
        cout << "\nWhat is your name?\n";
        cin >> name; 
        players << name;
        players.close();
        cout << "Entering..";
        chatw.open ("C:/Users/Pebsie/Dropbox/Public/chat.txt", fstream::out | fstream::app | fstream::ate);
        chatw << "***" << name << " Entered the game*** " << endl;
        chatw.close();
        while (1) {
            system("cls");
            ifstream myfile ("C:/Users/Pebsie/Dropbox/Public/chat.txt");
            if (myfile.is_open()) {
                while ( myfile.good() )
                {
                    getline (myfile,line);
                    cout << line << endl;
                }
                myfile.close();
            }

            cin >> option;
            if (option == "/refresh") {
                 //DO NOTHING
            }
            else if (option == "/clearchat") {
                chatw.open ("C:/Users/Pebsie/Dropbox/Public/chat.txt", fstream::out);
                chatw << name << " cleared the chat." << endl;
                chatw.close();
            }
            else {
                chatw.open ("C:/Users/Pebsie/Dropbox/Public/chat.txt", fstream::out | fstream::app | fstream::ate);
                chatw << name << ": " << option << endl;
                chatw.close();
            }
        }
        system("pause"); 
        chatw.open ("C:/Users/Pebsie/Dropbox/Public/chat.txt", fstream::out | fstream::app | fstream::ate);
        chatw << "***" << name << " Left the game..*** " << endl;
        chatw.close();
        return 0;
    } 
}
```

When I code it, I test it locally, but still write to it so that the users can see what I'm updating to it.

So, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT- My question, is how I would actually be able to write to and read from the dropbox file. It's public URL is http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17570838/chat.txt
/ how I could load the file from the online URL.

P.S It's just going to be used as a chat app for a test, it obviously isn't very good as it doesn't auto update.

Comment: So you're building it to let Dropbox do all the synchronization of the files and letting dropbox's infrastructure do your network traversal? That's an interesting approach. I can assure you that it is almost gauranteed to fail as a chat mechanism, but it's an interesting approach. Consider also asking for design help on Programmers.SE?

Comment: What is the question? it is difficult to tell what is being asked here. Do you want help writing your program, or is there a bug that needs fixed? please clarify.

Comment: What's the concrete question? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I've updated it with exactly what my question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) library. It supports many file transfer protocols, including HTTP. There is also [curlpp](http://curlpp.org/) which is a C++ wrapper around libcurl.

See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339) for an example.

Reading the file via HTTP should be fairly straightforward. Alas, I don't know what mechanism Dropbox uses to upload files (WebDAV?).