# open url mac osx c++

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, url, macos-carbon

How do I hit a url in C++, there are a ton of examples for Objective-C, but my application doesn't use objective-c and starts with main() and is all c/c++.  I was using URLSimpleDownload but it isn't working anymore (returns -50).  I don't want to open a webpage or browser, I simply need to hit a url from c/c++.

Answer (score 1):

You can take several of those `NSURL` examples you referred to, and just use the equivalent `CFURL*` APIs. Note: `CFURLRef` is an `NSURL*`. So you just need to figure out the corresponding `CFURL*` interface which an `NSURL`-based implementation uses.

This relationship where a CF-type is an NS-type is named "toll-free bridged".

Note that not everything will map one-to-one, NS-APIs have a lot of conveniences/additions -- it's better to think of it as an abstraction layer above CF-APIs.

Comment: I see there is a NSString stringWithContentsOfURL function that is exactly what I need, but there is no corresponding CFString function for it?

Comment: Create a cfdata intermediate

Answer (score 0):

**You could** try downloading and installing [cURLpp](http://code.google.com/p/curlpp/downloads/list) (code from [neuro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135549/neuro)'s [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1112084/1801602)):

```
// Edit : rewritten for cURLpp 0.7.3
// Note : namespace changed, was cURLpp in 0.7.2 ...
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>

// RAII cleanup
curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;

// standard request object.
curlpp::Easy myRequest;

// Set the URL.
myRequest.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Url(std::string("http://example.com")));

// Send request and get a result.
// By default the result goes to standard output.
// Here I use a shortcut to get it in a string stream ...
std::ostringstream os;
os << myRequest.perform();

string asAskedInQuestion = os.str();
```