# HTTP Request from Cpp File

Tags: php, c

I have a webpage, say at `www.mypage.com`, which uses `$_GET` to fetch data and then saves the fetched data into the `MySQL` database.

I need to send this `HTTP Request` from a Cpp File.

How can I send a `HTTP Request` from Cpp file?

Comment: If you mean "how to load html file by C/C++", then read about sockets and for example libcurl.

Comment: Are you on Linux? The easiest way is system("wget ..."). Now for the correct way you could open a socket, use a library etc..

Comment: @Eddy_Em : I dont want to load a page. I just want to send some data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make a HTTP request with C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, libcurl should be helpful. You can send some data by GET parameters or by POST and read responses. (Maybe necessary to verify a successful transmission) Here are some examples: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html