# Best option to get html source from a website.

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

Iam now making a program where user enters login, pasw and then program sends it to website with post method or somethink like that, and then retrvieves html source and puts it in string.

I cant find a best option to do this. Currently my program's ui is in Qt QML and main is in c++.

I have done this before with libcurl but I dont like, so maybe there is another option.

And another problem is that iam beginner and I know just C++ and Qml. I tried javascript but i cant get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. You can either write C++ code to make the call(which will require some sort of library to help you make the call) or you can make the call in JavaScript using an XMLHttpRequest(Which is provided natively by QML).

XMLHttpRequest example:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/declarative-xml-xmlhttprequest-xmlhttprequest-example-qml.html

For C++ I would refer you to [How do you make a HTTP request with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c) which discusses libraries that allow you to easily make the http calls in C++.