# Automatically Logging Into A Website From C++

Tags: c++, forms, google-drive-api, autologin

I'm trying to make an autorun app with c++ that doesn't have an UI, but it will log into google drive when u plug in the USB drive. I was wondering if there was a way to do this, either by using google api, or by detecting the field forms on the login screen, and automatically filling them in. Also this is going to be strictly a private software.

Comment: Yes, there's a way to do it.

Comment: first, love the username :) and, do you have an idea as to how to do that?

Comment: I would suggest C# with WebBrowser class but since you want c++, I guess curl? This is for manual logins, not google API.

Comment: I can do C#, I was just assuming C++ might have more accessbility to this type of thing, thanks, I'll take a look at that class :)

Answer (score 2):

Add one part [How do you make a HTTP request with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c) with two parts https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/.

Shake lightly. Chill and serve.

Optionally add for flavor: https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/web-server

However, I'm unable to find a c++ oath2 library. The closest thing I found was https://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/. If you find an oath library, please comment on this.

**UPDATE:**

POCO has a OAuth 1.0 implementation seen here: https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/tree/develop/Net/samples/TwitterClient/src

Also, according to [this landmark blog post](http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/), there are still many concerns about OAuth 2.0's security. The 1.0 implementation above is what I would attempt.

For more information on OAuth 2.0, see [RFC6749](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749.txt) and [RFC6750](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750.txt).