# winsock.h post request in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, networking, winsock

Q1:
I am trying to send and http post request using c or c++ and get the response
can some one provide me working code
or a tutorial for winsock so I can get started

Q2:
Is there any c/c++ networking library that only support windows (I am targeting windows only)

thanks in advance.

**Edite1:**
I got the answer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment (lib, "wsock32.lib")

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

#define BUFFERSIZE 1024
void die_with_error(char *errorMessage);
void die_with_wserror(char *errorMessage);

string HTTP_POST(string host,string path , string data){
    string request;
    string response;
    int resp_leng;

    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    int sock;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    char *ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 80;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << data.length();

    std::stringstream request2;

    request2 << "POST " << path << " HTTP/1.1"<<endl;
    request2 << "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)" << endl;
    //request2 << "" << endl;
    request2 << "Host: " << host << endl;
    request2 << "Content-Length: " << data.length() << endl;

    request2 << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" << endl;
    request2 << "Accept-Language: en-au" << endl;
    request2 << endl;
    request2 << data;
    request = request2.str();
    cout<< request << endl << "###################################################" << endl << endl;
    //init winsock
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData) != 0)
        die_with_wserror("WSAStartup() failed");
    //open socket
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
        die_with_wserror("socket() failed");

    //connect
    memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipaddress);
    serveraddr.sin_port        = htons((unsigned short) port);
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0)
        die_with_wserror("connect() failed");

    //send request
    if (send(sock, request.c_str(), request.length(), 0) != request.length())
        die_with_wserror("send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");

    //get response
    response = "";
    resp_leng= BUFFERSIZE;
    while (resp_leng == BUFFERSIZE)
    {
        resp_leng= recv(sock, (char*)&buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 0);
        if (resp_leng>0)
            response+= string(buffer).substr(0,resp_leng);
        //note: download lag is not handled in this code
    }

    //disconnect
    closesocket(sock);

    //cleanup
    WSACleanup();

    return  response;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string  host = "localhost",
            path = "/page.php",
            data = "somedata=data1$somedata2=data2";
    string res = HTTP_POST(host,path,data);
    cout << res << endl;
    cin.get();
}

void die_with_error(char *errorMessage)
{
    cerr << errorMessage << endl;
    cin.get();
    exit(1);
}

void die_with_wserror(char *errorMessage)
{
    cerr << errorMessage << ": " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    cin.get();
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with a library that supports another OS too?

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c

Comment: For C++, I suggest http://cpp-netlib.org/

Comment: Regarding HTTP: libcurl or poco are options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used curl a lot for this. Here you can find a bunch of examples for c++
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html

Answer (score 2):

These both are C (not C++) libs but they might be useful: libcURL which is the most popular or Libwww which is not so popular but is sponsored by W3C

Comment: tnx I'll go with libcURL