# how to make asynchronous http request response communication(request in vc++ and response in java)

Tags: java, c++, visual-c++, httprequest, httpresponse

Hi i want to make http request response communication protocol between one native application and web module. Native application is in vc++ while web module is in java. i gone through [this] ([How do you make a HTTP request with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c/1012577#1012577)) it is useful for only http request in vc++. i implement simple file sending to web with curl and its working. Native app send request to web module(which is in java) is also working. but i have no idea how response from web module(java) send to native app.. is anyone here suggest me any API/Class/Function for communication protocol between vc++ and java?

Comment: The question isn't quite clear. Entire HTTP protocol is request/response based, so if you need somthing from a web-service you need to make an appropriate request first.

Comment: There're some extensions to the HTTP protocol which allow to receive data from server w/o a prior explicit request but you should clarify your situation, your problem so we could give reasonable advices.

Comment: pardon for english. Ilet me explain you again..i send one request to web in c++. web module has to response which is in java. how java response to request which come from vc++

Comment: Ahh, the key word in your question is "asynchronous", right?

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous requests handling on the Java server side can be done using [Servlet 3.0 API](http://docs.coreservlets.com/servlet-3.0-api/) There're a lot of tutorials, [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/async-servlet-feature-of-servlet-3.html) is the one of them for example.