# Sending a file from C/C++ application to java Web Application

Tags: c++, web-applications

Does the socket program is only option by which, i can transfer / copy files from client application (developed in C) to a java web application hosted on tomcat?
file size can be from 50kb to 3 mb.
Is there any other alternative also?
Nikhil Gothankar

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries that provide a nice interface to make http requests. `libcurl` is a good example as it provides almost any web protocol known to man, but a more complete overview is given in this thread [How do you make a HTTP request with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c)

Comment: I also found found curl is good option for my requirement. I try to build my application with curl by including all header files and curllib and curllib.dll. My code compiles successfully but it is failed while building and throwing some 10 linking error. I already added .lib file using linker option in visual studio but....

Comment: curls itself also has quite some dependencies `libssl` and `libldap` to name a few. Unfortunately I've got zero experience manually installing libraries in VS, but a quick search gives me multiple tutorials (including some here on stackoverflow) on how to set it up by hand. You could, however, also consider using [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/) which is package manager for visual studio which allows you to download and set up almost any library with a single command.