# PHP-HTML variable Communication

Tags: php, html, sockets

1. My C++ program communicates to my PHP server through a TCP socket.
2. Data is sent on the server at periodic intervals.
3. I want the Data sent on the server to be displayed on my HTML page.

I am new to HTTP/PHP programming. How can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to revise this question, you don't say if your storing the data in a database or some other persistent storage method once your data gets to PHP.

You need to give more details on the exact nature of your setup in order for a better response.

Comment: no I do not store my data. simple `write` from c++ and `read` in php

Comment: How are you writing your data to PHP? The question you have asked is just way too vague and ambiguous. You need to provide more detail.

Comment: through a TCP socket, c++ `write(cid, &msg, strlen(msg));` and on the php server `$data = socket_read($sockses, 1024)`

Comment: Im removing my awnser since this entire question seems to be a downvote spree and nothing more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, the most simple should be this one (if your c++ program run out of the server):

create a "upload.php" file in your server with:

```
<?php
  $a = $_POST["data"];
  //$a contains all your data
?>
```

send a POST message to

```
http://yourserver/upload.php
```

from your c++ program with 'data' parameter containing your data message. You can use libcurl to achieve this. Here is an example [How do you make a HTTP request with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c)

Answer (score 0):

> c++ to PHP use Socket
>
> PHP to HTML use HTTP
>
> To run PHP you will need to install apache.