# HTTP POST request with C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, http-request

Before you flag this post as a duplicate: I've tried all "solutions" i could find around the internet and stackoverflow but got nothing to work, mostly because some functions were deprecated or I was missing some libraries or something else.

I got the following code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c) (the second answer because I couldnt get libcurl to work), but this doesnt work for me because Visual Studio 2015 tells me to use [`GetAddrInfoW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms738519(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of `gethostbyname()` because it's deprecated, so i tried to do so and ended up like this:

```
WSADATA wsaData;

if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
{
    return;
}


SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
struct hostent* host = new hostent();
GetAddrInfoW((PCWSTR)"www.google.com", (PCWSTR)"http", nullptr, (PADDRINFOW*)host);
SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)"192.168.xxx.xxx");

if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0)
{
    return;
}

send(Socket, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", strlen("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"), 0);
char buffer[10000];
int nDataLength;
while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 10000, 0)) > 0)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r')
    {
        i += 1;
    }
}
closesocket(Socket);
WSACleanup();
```

That wont work neither because of a nullpointer

(Visual Studio says: Exception triggered at 0x00AE5F02 in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading at position 0x00000000 [...])

and it's totally logical to me but I don't have a clue how to do it correctly so if anyone does, please tell me how cause I'm getting a little depressed right now.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious bug is that your inner while loop is infinite.
You need to limit it using the `i` and `nDataLength` variables.