# How to send Query string using simple http get request (windows socket)

Tags: http, get, query-string

Im using this example as reference :
[How do you make a HTTP request with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c)
which working fine ( the first example in the accepted answer ) 
i wander how can i send Query string so in the server i can parse it .
so it will act as :

```
http//127.0.0.1/?test1=1&test2=2
```

where here or in other place should it be ?

```
  send(Socket, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: http//127.0.0.1\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", strlen("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: http//127.0.0.1\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"), 0);
```

Comment: What happens actually when you replace the `http//127.0.0.1` with `http//127.0.0.1/?test1=1&test2=2`? Doesn't this do what you want?

Comment: i figure it i can set it after the "GET /"

Comment: That doesn't really have much to do with c++ specifically.

Comment: Also if you found a solution, you may consider to answer that question yourself.

Comment: it will look like GET /?querystring HTTP./1.1 etc