# C++ request HTTPS website with GET, read the returned data from website

Tags: php, c++, sockets, https, get

first of all I want to assure you that I have been looking for this for multiple hours, I found many results but none of them seemed to work for me, it could also be possible that I'm just too dumb to put in the data concerning the website correctly.

Basically what I need is a request to a HTTPS website with one item in the GET part. My php script then takes that item and checks if it is in my database, then displays 1 or 0 on the website.

The address would look like this:

> www.mysite.com/main/sub.php?item=ABC123

It doesn't matter if the connection will be established using sockets.

Sadly, I already tried and overwrote my method so often that I can't show my sample to ask you what exactly is wrong. [How do you make a HTTP request with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c][1]) is a sample code for a method using sockets that I tried to modify yesterday.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make a HTTP request with C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c)

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Recover your code, then post it here. Then we can tell you what you're doing wrong.