# Sending images to server?

Tags: file, transfer

I have to write a C++ applicaton that has to read images from a local directory on client computer (linux, ubuntu) and send them to a server (linux, ubuntu).

There will be almost 1000 of such clients.

Assuming that the rest of my program is written in C++ I need some hint on what library+technologies to use to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on a number of variables.

First, determine what type of format does the server accept? Is it SOAP or not? If yes, you can stream data to the server. Otherwise, you need to read the entire file first and then, send it.

Second, here is a very good article on how to create a web request in C++. Have a look at it: [How do you make a HTTP request with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c)

Comment: I have full control over clients and server. I am going to have 1000 raspberry pi computers with cameras. The goal is to capture one image per second per camera and do some preprocessing on the image and then send the image to the remote server for further processing.