# C++ libcurl - Can't retrieve whole html content from URL

Tags: c++, screen-scraping, libcurl

Using **C++** and the **libcurl** library, I'm trying to get the full HTML from this website https://www.nutritionix.com/food/Banana in this way:

```c++
int main(){
   std::string content;
   curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
   CURL *curl = nullptr;
   curl = curl_easy_init();
   if (curl) {
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.nutritionix.com/food/Banana" );
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
       CURLcode code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
       curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
   }
   curl_global_cleanup();
   std::cout << content << std::endl;
   system("pause");
}
```

The `writer` function is defined in this way:

```c++
static int writer(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string *writerData) {
   if (writerData == NULL)
       return 0;
   writerData->append(data, size*nmemb);
   return size * nmemb;
}
```

In this way I can get just few HTML code, but how can I retrieve the full HTML content to parse it at a later stage?

Comment: Try `http://` instead, otherwise you need SSL support.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. Anyway, using `http://`, I get even less.

Comment: Then try [CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html).

Comment: @nicoperillo i updated my answer with full explanation and sample

Comment: @Axalo I just edited my code, now there's also a `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`. Is that what you meant? Anyway the results don't change.

Comment: I just checked the website, you need to use their [API](https://www.nutritionix.com/business/api).

Answer (score 1):

> You can't, or better to say: You have the whole html content of the website call.

A simply http request on modern websites will only return some in your case 70 chars long response with some scripts and meta data. The scripts execute on load and will fill up the pages content afterwards.

**Try it yourself**

- visit https://www.nutritionix.com/food/Banana
- Ctrl + Shift + i
- go to the network tab and reload the page
- click the first item on the list named "Banana"
- click on "response" on the right

This is the content your string contains after you executed the code above

Comment: Okay I see, in fact I get just a bunch of scripts and meta data. So I think the best way to achieve my goal is to execute an already working Python script from my C++.

Comment: Korni, is it a good idea (in your opinion) to make an XMLHTTPREQUEST to retrieve the information I need from the website? I analyzed the Network Panel in Chrome like you said and I noticed I need to make an XHR request to get data about "nutrients".
Could I do this using libcurl?

Comment: I can't tell sorry