# How do I write the WordPress password encryption algorithm in C++?

Tags: php, c++, wordpress, encryption

I have searched long for this answer, but it does not seem to be out there.  I have a Wordpress (recent version) website with user accounts.  I have a C++ program that users can use.  The C++ program needs to authenticate users, and query some website data about them.  As far as I can tell, that means the C++ program must get the clear password, encrypt it with the same algorithm as Wordpress, then compare the encrypted password from the Wordpress table.  I can see the Wordpress user table, and the encrypted passwords there.  I have also experimented with this simple script to verify this is the PHP algorithm that can do the exact WordPress encryption:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
  include 'wp-includes/pluggable.php';
  require_once 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php';
  $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);
  $plain_password = $argv[1];
  $password_hashed = $argv[2];

  if($wp_hasher->CheckPassword($plain_password, $password_hashed)) {
    echo "yes\n";
  } else {
    echo "no\n";
  }
?>
```

I can't do a system call from C++ to run this php script, because the app is on a client computer that may not have php.  So, basically...how do I write this in C++, using some respected 3rd party encryption library?  I have used openssl before, but anything will do as long as it is cross platform (mac/windows).  After I have the encrypted password in C++, the plan is to URL a php script and post user and encrypted password.  I can't have that script do the encryption, because then I would have to pass the clear password across the internet.

Comment: https://www.openwall.com/phpass/ check this because wp is using this to hash passwords.

Comment: create a API call it from c++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c

Comment: I guess phpass is saying that it uses bcrypt (C library) underneath, so that sounds like the right path.  I thought that there would be many ways to use bcrypt, so how would I know exactly how phpass does...but maybe it is obvious when I get into it.