# options is not a member of curlpp

Tags: c++, libcurl, curlpp

I was recently working on a project to make HTTP requests in C++. I found the libcurl library with the curlpp wrapper in [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/). But when I set it up, it tells me that `options` is not a member of `curlpp`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "curlpp/cURLpp.hpp"
#include "curlpp/Options.hpp"

curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;
std::ostringstream os;
using namespace BlaguesAPI;
int main() {
  os << curlpp::options::Url(std::string("http://youtube.com")); // Here
  return 0;
}
```

In my workspace folder, I added the include folder of the official `.zip` file available for [download here](https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp/releases/tag/v0.8.1).

Did I miss something?

Comment: `options` is indeed in the `curlpp` namespace. Did you try using `#include <...>` instead of `#include "..."` for the curlpp headers? [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/) However, `curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;` and `std::ostringstream os;` should be inside your `main()`, not in global scope. And why are you using `using namespace BlaguesAPI;` when you are not using anything from the `BlaguesAPI` namespace?

Comment: For BlaguesAPI i deleted the code that didn't matter here, I just forgot this line. I moved `curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;` and `std::ostringstream os;` to my `main()` but nothing changed. And the reason why I'm using `#include "..."` and not `#include <...>` is because I use `curlpp` as a local folder (I can't manage to run c++ on VSCode so I use [replit](https://repl.it))