# How can I fetch data from a website inside a C++ program

Tags: c++

I want to write a program in C++ that helps to manage my hockey pool, and one of the key things i will need to do is read off the schedule for the week ahead. I was hoping to use the NHL website. is there any way to have the program download the HTML file for a given url, and then parse that? i suppose that once i have the file downloaded, Simple file I/O would do, but im not sure how to download the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically reading a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389069/programmatically-reading-a-web-page)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would use some library providing Http abstraction.

For example:

**[cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/)**

```
#include <boost/network/protocol/http/client.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    boost::network::http::client client;
    boost::network::http::client::request request("http://www.example.com");
    request << boost::network::header("Connection", "close");
    boost::network::http::client::response response = client.get(request);

    std::cout << body(response);
}
```

I do not think it can get much easier than that

On GNU/Linux compile with:

```
g++ -I. -I$BOOST_ROOT -L$BOOST_ROOT/stage/lib -lboost_system -pthread my_main.cpp
```

**[QHttp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qhttp.html)**

Example for this could get quite long,
since QHttp can send only non-blocking requests (that means, that you have to catch some signals reporting that the request was finished, etc.).
But the documentation is superb, so it should not be a problem. :)

Comment: +1 Although this library is not yet accepted, it seems elegant.

Comment: @Palmik is there an updated version of this, I'm getting compiler errors.

Answer (score 6):

Using [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is one option. [Here](http://www.luckyspin.org/?p=28) is an example of using it with C++ to download contents of a webpage as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to compile it and link with:

```
    g++ -I. -I/usr/include -lboost_thread -lboost_system 
    -lcppnetlib-client-connections -lcppnetlib-server-parsers 
    -lcppnetlib-uri -pthread main.cpp
```