# Trying to access a string from a website c++

Tags: c++, libraries

I've been trying to figure this out for the better part of the day, but due to my lack of knowledge of c++ and libraries, I've made little progress.

I'm trying to access a page that contains a single string, and basically read it.

I've attempted to use curl to access the internet, but I can't seem to be able to get it working. Then I came across this post that has a simple enough solution ([post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488128/how-can-i-fetch-data-from-a-website-inside-a-c-program)). I downloaded the zip file from the cpp-netlib link, extracted it to a folder containing a .cpp file with the provided code, and ran the g++ command. This is the error it's giving me:

```
testing.cpp:1:50: fatal error: boost/network/protocol/http/client.hpp: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what I can do? (for what it's worth, this code is meant to be cross-compiled and run on an [omega-2](https://onion.io/omega2/) eventually).

Comment: Since you want to run the code on an Omega-2, can you do the program in Python instead of C++?

Comment: You need to install the `boost` library: http://www.boost.org/.