# Reading the content of a PHP from C++

Tags: c++, http

I am trying to read the content of a PHP / HTML file on a remote web server using C++, but haven't found a way to do it. I want to pass GET statements to it, so `http://example.com/login.php?user=abc&password=def`.
How would I do it?

Comment: the way you can see in the address bar of this very browser window. it is called HTTP. and the server side language of the other party doesn't matter anything.

Comment: it's unclear to me: do you want the *source* of the PHP script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically reading a web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389069/programmatically-reading-a-web-page)

Comment: Please search before posting. This question has been posted many, many, many, many, many, many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use an external library. [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is popular and fairly easy to use.

Here's a simple example, you need to add error checking though:

```
string data;
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url_.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curlWrite);
curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Your callback would look something like this:

```
size_t curlWrite(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *usrPtr)
{
    size_t bytes = size * nmemb;
    string *data = static_cast<string *>(usrPtr);
    data->append(static_cast<const char *>(ptr), bytes);
    return bytes;
}
```

You can add your `GET` parameters on the end of the URL.