# Reading a webpage, handle a proxy redirect C#

Tags: c#, c++, proxy, web-scraping

I want to scrape some data off of a web page but I am behind a "corporate" proxy of sorts.

I found C++ that works here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12374434/1454861

My problem is that I have not been able to find a C# solution that will do the same thing. Do I just need to use raw socket code to accomplish this or is there a more elegant/high-level library approach that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For C#, if the proxy is set in IE, C# code will that proxy as the default proxy, you don't need to specify it. Or you can use [WebRequest.Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.proxy.aspx) to specify the proxy.

Comment: I used WebProxy and specified the proxy but still ended up with 401 Unauthorized or 403 Forbidden responses.

Comment: Did you try just set the proxy in IE and let the C# program use the default proxy?