# Editing online files using C++

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am pretty new to file handling in C++. So I was wondering if it is possible to access or edit an online text file using C++. Like is it possible to open a file like the following :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    fstream one("http://xproweb.in/sri.txt");
    char a[20];
    one>>a;
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

Or is there any other way that I could access online files in C++ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically reading a web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389069/programmatically-reading-a-web-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to read a web page, so [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389069/programmatically-reading-a-web-page) contains the answer.

Comment: Why didn't you just mark the question as a duplicate?

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah I must have a reputation >= 50 to be able to comment on a post.