# URLDownloadToFile not doing anything

Tags: c++

URLDownloadToFile not working this is what im doing

```
URLDownloadToFile( NULL, "https://pastebin.com/raw/Q91mE8Qe", "C:/text.txt", 0, NULL);
```

and it's not download the file.. any help would be cool

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically reading a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389069/programmatically-reading-a-web-page)

Comment: @frslm Check the new question.. I am going to do it a different way

Comment: What is the actual return value of `URLDownloadToFile()`?  Note that `URLDownloadToFile()` is very unreliable and lacks good error reporting.  Consider switching to WinInet/WinHTTP instead, or any other HTTP library, for that matter.

Comment: You should add tags with more information. If you *just* have the C++ tag, it looks like you’re asking about generic C++, when [`URLDownloadToFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123(v=vs.85).aspx) appears to be Microsoft-specific.

Comment: I expect that the issue is you don’t have permission to write to `C:\text.txt` as whatever user you’re running your program from, but I definitely don’t have enough information to be confident in that.

Comment: Thanks everyone.. I solved it

Answer (score 0):

fixed it with

```
URLDownloadToFile( NULL, "https://pastebin.com/raw/Q91mE8Qe/index.html", "C:/text.txt", 0, NULL);
```

I just forgot to include /index.html